# Linked List in Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, binary-tree

I'm trying to solve : https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-178/problems/linked-list-in-binary-tree/

I have the following solution :

```java
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    boolean ans;
    ListNode originalHead;
    public boolean isSubPath(ListNode head, TreeNode root) {
        this.ans = false;
        originalHead = head;
        traverse(head, root);
        return ans;
    }

    public void traverse(ListNode head, TreeNode root) {
        if(head == null) {
            ans = true;
            return;
        }
        if(root == null) return;

        if(!ans && root.val == head.val) traverse(head.next, root.right);
        if(!ans && root.val == head.val) traverse(head.next, root.left);
        if(!ans) traverse(originalHead, root.right);
        if(!ans) traverse(originalHead, root.left);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if this solution has a time complexity of O(n^2) or not. I ask this since I'm encountering a Time Limit Exceeded error for one of the test cases in the test suite.

I do see other O(n^2) solutions passing though.

Appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *n* is the number of vertices in the tree, then your algorithm's worst-case time complexity is in  Θ(2<sup>*n*</sup>) rather than *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

This worst case occurs when every non-leaf node of the tree has just one child, the linked list is longer than the tree is deep, and all of the nodes in the tree *and* the linked list all have the same value. When that happens, you end up making *all* of your recursive calls — your `if`-conditions are always met — so each time you call `traverse` on a node, you call `traverse` *twice* on its child node. So you call `traverse` once on the root node, twice on its child, four times on its grandchild, eight times on its great-grandchild, etc., which is Θ(2<sup>*n*</sup>) if there are *n* nodes.